# Weird routing behaviour in NativeScript v2.0 with Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript

I've been testing out NativeScript and come across the following issue:

I have declared these routes in my app.component.ts file:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: "/Home", component: HomePage, name: "Home", useAsDefault: true },
  { path: "/Scan", component: ScanPage, name: "Scan"},
  { path: "/Webview", component: WebviewPage, name: "Webview"}
])
```

In my HomePage component I have declared the following methods:

```
export class HomePage {

    constructor(private _router: Router) {}

    public goToScanPage() {
        this._router.navigate(["Scan"])
    }

    public goToWebviewPage() {
        this._router.navigate(["Webview"])
    }
}
```

Now, the weird thing is that when I load the app on either android or ios and fire the goToScanPage() method it all works and I can see the new page, but when I tap the button to fire goToWebviewPage() I get a blank page. From what I gather, the underlying component is loaded but the view is blank. When I've replaced the template files from one component with the other I can see the other view when using goToScanPage() so there's nothing wrong with the template file. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You're using router-deprecated and I think everything is moving now to the new Angular router though it currently seems a bit buggy to me.

Comment: Thanks @HK1, I'm aware it's deprecated and was just wondering whether there was any fault on my part for it not working as I thought it would. Anyway, I got it working when I changed the route name to something other than 'webview'. Perhaps there was a naming clash or perhaps it's just a coincidence...